# Algorithm for building a string by appending and cloning substrings

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, optimization

I have a problem where I need to construct a given string from scratch for a minimum cost by either:

Appending a new character for a cost A

Appending a substring of my existing string for a cost B

E.g. for a string "abcabc" with a cost of A = 10, B = 11

a 10
ab 20
abc 30
abcabc 41

First I tried a greedy algorithm but it didn't give the optimal answer for this problem. I had the idea to use the dijkstra algorithm and a priority queue, so for each popped node I calculated the possibilities for A and B and pushed the new nodes back onto the queue. Since you can't change keys on the priority queue I use an int array ("visited") to keep track of the visited nodes.

However my solution isn't fast enough to finish 30000 char strings in 2 seconds so I wanted to ask for some pointers on how I could optimise/change my approach.

```
typedef pair<int, int> iPair;
int solve(string &s, int a, int b) {
    priority_queue<iPair, iPair<Node>, greater<iPair>> pq;
    int visited[s.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
        visited[i] = -1;
    pq.push(make_pair(a, 0));
    iPair p;
    while (!pq.empty()) {
        p = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        if (visited[p.second] == -1)
            visited[p.second] = 1;
        else
            continue;
        if (p.second == s.size() - 1)
            break;

        // Handle append costs
        pq.push(make_pair(p.first + a, p.second + 1));

        // Handle clone costs
        int j;
        int i = p.second;

        if (s.size()  > 2*i + 2)
            j = 2*i + 1;
        else
            j = s.size() - 1;

        for (; j > i + 1; --j) {
            if(s.substr(0, i+1).find(s.substr(i+1, j-i)) != string::npos) {
        pq.push(make_pair(p.first + b, j));               
                break;
                }
        }
    }
    return p.current_cost;
}
```

As I say I'm looking for how I'm out of ideas how how to optimise this code and I'm not sure Dijkstra is even the right approach.  I read up how A* search can speed up Dijkstra but I couldn't come up with an easy heuristic function.

Comment: By analogy with straight line path planning and A*, wouldn't some expression of the minimum cost work -- something like 10 * length of desired string?

Comment: In your example, why is `abc` not 21 - for `ab` (11) + `c` (10)?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Why will `ab` be `11`?

Comment: @vivek_23: `Appending a substring of my existing string for a cost B` - `ab` is a substring of the existing string, but perhaps I am misunderstanding, hence the question.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Fair enough. I see the confusion.This does need a bit of clarification because we could directly append the entire string as it is also a substring.

Comment: @esperski Could you please elaborate on the conditions? Or if you got this from somewhere, can you directly copy paste the problem statement in your post?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I think we're starting with an empty string. Appending a, b, and c each cost 10. A means the cost of appending a character; B means the cost of appending a substring.

Comment: Do we have a limited number of possible characters in the string? (Like [A-Za-z]?)

Comment: Yes it's only lowercase letters, the comment above is correct about the conditions.

Comment: lmao senir been messing up students mental health with this for 3+ years now. what a c l o w n

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but a first few steps to a possible solution.

The theoretical solution is the following:

1. Let S[i] the cost of the substring to the i. char.
2. S[0] = 0, S[1] = A
3. S[x] = minimum of S[x-1] + A, or any S[x-k] + B if substring(x-k, x) can be found in substring(0, x-k)

So we need to calculate the S[x] values incrementally, based on the previous values in the array. Calculating S[x-1]+A is simple, but calculating the minimum value for S[x-k]+B is quite expensive, because we need to find all occurrences of all possible substrings.

In theory it's possible that S[x]>S[x+k] (in certain A, B and str values)

So the question is how can we optimise calculating the substrings.

I think some kind of unique 'longest common substring' graph could help somehow, however I haven't found the solution yet.
Another optimisation if we maintain an ordered list of costs for each position and start looking up the possible substrings from the cheapest position instead of starting from the longest possible substring. (the cost of adding a substring is independent from the length of the substring)